# how to query JSON in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have following JSON. I want to store it in MongoDB as Json and query it. How can I do it?

JSON

```
{
"id": 4,
"user": {
      "firstname":"Finn",
      "lastname":"Balor",
      "email":["fb@wwe.com","fb1@wwe.com"],
      "password":"whateverHisTaglineIs",
      "address":{
        "street":"64 victoria street", 
        "country":"UK"
      }
   }
}
```

I am storing this as the following document

```
> db.users.insert({id: 4,user: {firstname:"Finn",lastname:"Balor",email:["fb@wwe.com","fb1@wwe.com"],password:"whateverHisTaglineIs",address:{street:"64 victoria street", country:"UK"}}})
```

how can I query this record using country as selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query like below, go through [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/) and learn MongoDB from  [MongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com/).

```
db.users.find({"user.address.country": "UK"})
```